# How to prevent TypeError: e.target.getAttribute is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What I'm trying to do is the `inner code (result)` will only work when there's an attribute of `Validity`.
But since my target doesn't have an attribute of `Validity`, I want to prevent the inner code to run by having an `if checking`.

What can I do to check/prevent the error of `TypeError: e.target.getAttribute is not a function`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or `hasOwnProperty()` method

Comment: `e.target.hasOwnProperty('validity')` this worked. thank you

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is irrelevant in this case (it is relevant when checking for existence via the prototype chain must be prevented). Checking for `e.target.validity` (eg. to see that it is defined (or not undefined) and thus likely a function) is sufficient.